# Can I limit the character set for a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a bitmap font which which doesn't have every single character, such as accented characters (é î ü etc) or symbols such as "¥" or © which I'm using to display usernames in a Highscore table for a game.

Is it possible to limit the UIKit keyboard to certain characters, or only allow certain characters in the UITextField? Or will I have to roll my own input mechanism? I'm thinking and old school, Arcade style, one letter at a time "thing" would be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the following UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Comment: I see what you mean; But due to the sheer number of characters available to iPhone users around the world, that range would be massive. I'm just going to use an installed font instead. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 9):

Using the UITextFieldDelegate method mentioned by intregus, you can do this quite easily:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Only characters in the NSCharacterSet you choose will insertable.
    NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefgABCDEFG"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad` for your `UITextField`.  It only has letters and numbers on it:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Interface builder you can link and get the event for "Editing changed" in any of your function. Now there you can put check for the length

```
- (IBAction)onValueChange:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *text = nil;
    int MAX_LENGTH = 20;
    switch ([sender tag] ) 
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            text = myEditField.text;
            if (MAX_LENGTH < [text length]) {
                myEditField.text = [text substringToIndex:MAX_LENGTH];
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```