# UITextField Text Only

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am trying to make a UITextField meant for names, but can't figure out how to restrict it to letters ONLY. I know numbers only is possible, but how is letters only possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863678/can-i-limit-the-character-set-for-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegate and implement:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Validate the replacement string here.